# Parent Child Record Relationship in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to figure out the best way, in SQL, to query on a Parent / Child relationship. Some of the parent fields will be the data for the child. Here is an example:

```
ID     Field1       Field2         ParentId
--------------------------------------------
1      stuff        moreStuff      0
2      childStuff   (from parent)  1
```

So, Field2 for a child would be the value of whatever the parent's is. I need to figure out how to write my SQL so that when the records get pulled back Field@ for the child would be "moreStuff". I am using SQL server 2008.
 Thank you.

Comment: Missing specification: Should the query be recursive or only one level? In other words, if a row's parent also has a parent, should the child get the grandparent's Field2 or the parent's Field2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming Field2 cannot be NULL, you could use a LEFT JOIN with COALESCE:

```
SELECT T1.ID, T1.Field1, COALESCE(T2.Field2, T1.Field2) AS Field2, T1.ParentID
FROM Table1 T1
LEFT JOIN Table1 T2
ON T1.ParentID = T2.ID
```

If that Field2 can be NULL, replace the coalesce expression with the following:

```
CASE WHEN T2.Id IS NULL THEN T1.Field2 ELSE T2.Field2 END AS Field2
```

Answer (score 1):

A self join should do the trick for you in this case.

```
SELECT child.ID, 
       child.Field1, 
       parent.Field2, 
       child.ParentID
FROM   MyTable child JOIN MyTable parent ON child.ParentID = parent.ID
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a [self join](http://databases.about.com/od/sql/a/selfjoins.htm) on the table:

```
SELECT parent.Field1, parent.Field2, child.ID
FROM myTable child
  INNER JOIN myTable parent
  ON child.ParentId = parent.ID
```

Answer (score 1):

It is common for these kind of hierarchical queries to have a root node, a prime mover, a parent who is not themselves a child.  That is, records where `ParentId` is null (or in your case 0, which I presume is not a real ID).  If such be the case here you'll need to use an OUTER join rather than an INNER one...

```
SELECT parent.Field1, parent.Field2, child.ID 
FROM myTable child 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN myTable parent 
    ON child.ParentId = parent.ID 
/
```

Comment: You are correct. I used 0 for the ParentID assuming it can't be null and if set to 0 it does not have a parent. Thanks!

Comment: @DDiVita - Using 0 is problematic, because it means you cannot enforce the parent-child relationship with a foreign key.  NULL is troublesome but magic values are worse.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a pretty good article on Storing Hierarchical Data in a Database geared towared PHP/MySQL users: http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/hierarchical-data-database